# Adding tests while refactoring in test driven development

Tags: unit-testing, refactoring, tdd

Let's say that I am refactoring some classes that have unit tests already written. Let's assume that the test coverage is reasonable in the sense that it covers most use cases.

While refactoring I change some implementations. Move some variables, add/remove a few, abstract out things into some functions etc. The api of the classes and it's function has remained the same though.

Should I be adding tests when I am refactoring these classes? Or should I add a new test for every bit of refactoring? This is what I usually do when I am building up code rather than refactoring.

PS: Apologies if this is really vague.

Comment: Somewhat subjective. What happens to your existing tests during the refactoring? Do they continue to work, or break because they are tied to the underlying implementation? What benefit are you expecting from the new tests? Do you feel the new code isn't covered sufficiently? Are you introducing new error possibilities/conditions? What type of tests do you write? What is your approach to mocking? How big is the refactoring? They all influence what approach a developer is likely to take...

Comment: Most of the tests continue to work - few need changes. Thanks for pointing out the things I should keep in mind. To be honest, I am looking for a way to think about these questions.

Answer (score 2):

Usually unit tests are work-/design-/use case-specifications of how your refactored [System Under Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test)/[Class Under Test](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ClassUnderTest) (eg.: classes) should really work. So by stating this I would really just go as:

1. Write the test according to your specification
2. Refactor the code to adhere to the specification
3. Check the assertation result of the test

In practice I have came to the conclusion that you don't need to test each and every line of your code just for the sake of high percentage of code coverage, but make sure you always test parts of your code where the *behaviour* or *logic* lies.

Answer (score 2):

If your changes are verified by current tests, there's no need to add new ones. Check your code coverage. If there are holes in your new code, that means you made an unverified functional change.

New tests might be valuable if a newly extracted class is moved to another project, where you don't have the original tests.